# Change hover text

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code:

```
x=["a","b","c","d"]
y1=[1,3,7,2]
y2=[3,6,1,2]
y3=[0.25, 0.33, 0.875, 0.5]
y4=[0.75, 0.66, 0.125, 0.5]
fig = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(
        name='Data 1',
        x=x,
        y=y1,
        marker=dict(color="red"),
        line=dict(width=3),
        mode='lines',
        line_shape='spline',
        stackgroup='one'
   ),
    go.Scatter(
        name='Data 2',
        x=x,
        y=y2,
        marker=dict(color="blue"),
        line=dict(width=3),
        mode='lines',
        line_shape='spline',
        stackgroup='one'
   )
])

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode="x unified",
)
    
fig.show()
```

And it creates the following image:
[image]

How can I change it that it shows in the hoverover not the data from the plot but the data from y3 and y4?

In this example, I would like to show Data 2: 0.125% and Data 1: 0.875%

Comment: The figure doesn't have any mapping of the data from y3 and y4 with x. Shouldn't it be mapped first (may be by creating two more `go.Scatter` objects)?

Comment: I only want to map the data from y1 and y2 and show in the hoverover the data from y3 and y4. Is this possible?

Comment: I think so. You can create a scatterplot of y3 and y4 in the figure and set its opacity to zero.

Comment: Wouldn't it then show all 4 data points in the hoverover? I tried but I might not find the right solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display different data in the hover text, you can use the custom data feature to add it to the display. I simply added the additional data by opening a blank space, as there is no mention of how to display it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x=["a","b","c","d"]
y1=[1,3,7,2]
y2=[3,6,1,2]
y3=[0.25, 0.33, 0.875, 0.5]
y4=[0.75, 0.66, 0.125, 0.5]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name='Data 1',
    x=x,
    y=y1,
    customdata=y3,
    marker=dict(color="red"),
    line=dict(width=3),
    mode='lines',
    line_shape='spline',
    stackgroup='one',
    hovertemplate='%{y} %{customdata}'
   )
)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name='Data 2',
    x=x,
    y=y2,
    customdata=y4,
    marker=dict(color="blue"),
    line=dict(width=3),
    mode='lines',
    line_shape='spline',
    stackgroup='one',
    hovertemplate='%{y} %{customdata}'
   )
)

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode="x unified",
)
    
fig.show()
```

[image]